# align 12*12 matrix in center

Tags: matrices

[image: **I have used \begin{bmatrix} and \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} to get this matrix . how do i assign it in center or scale this matrix .....?**]
I have used \begin{bmatrix} and \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} to get this matrix . how do i assign it in center or scale this matrix .....?

Comment: Define submatrices and make `K` a 4x4 matrix. It will still cover less space.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: i dont know how to do that, if posssible can you please explain or any help regarding the alignment of matrix in center

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following (with no attempt for aesthetics)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
We did symmetric matrix stuff. Let $K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4$ be symmetric matrices defined as 
\[
\mathbb{J} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix},\ 
K_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\star&\star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}
      \end{bmatrix},\
K_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}&\frac{12EI}{L^2}\\
                      \star&\star&\star&\frac{12EI}{L^2}
      \end{bmatrix}
\]
then 
\[
K = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{EA}{L}\mathbb{J}&&&\\&K_2&&\\&&K_3&\\&&&\frac{JG}{L}\mathbb{J}\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You.  I have another matrix which is even bigger than this,Can you help me with aligning matrix in Landscape mode ..?